# fastest query to select specific row when using distinct + filter

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Table answers:

```
Answer ID  | User ID | Question ID | deleted
1          | 1       |  1          | f
2          | 1       |  2          | f
3          | 1       |  2          | f
4          | 1       |  1          | t
5          | 2       |  1          | f
6          | 2       |  2          | f
7          | 2       |  2          | f
```

I want to select all answers distinct on `(userID, questionID)` using the latest answer (based on the highest id) and from this result set I want to remove all entries having `deleted = t`.

So my result should be

```
Answer ID  | User ID | Question ID | deleted
3          | 1       |  2          | f
5          | 2       |  1          | f
7          | 2       |  2          | f
```

I guess we are not able to do it with generated query methods from the interface? I am using a `@Query` annotation instead:

```
@Query("SELECT a1 FROM answer a1 WHERE ... ")
findLatestAnswers();
```

I came up with this (sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/02339/8/0 ) and am not even using `distinct` or `group by` nor `order by`. It is doing the job but seems to be very inefficient for larger data sets? What would be a faster statement?

```
SELECT * FROM answer a1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( -- where no newer answer exists
           SELECT * FROM answer a2
           WHERE a1.user_id = a2.user_id
                   AND a1.question_id = a2.question_id
                   AND a1.id < a2.id
  )
  AND a1.deleted = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem using `distinct` or `group by` or aggregation functions. These are essential in datawarehouse or analytics software where millions or records are processed in every request (billions and trillions in bigdata).

The only adjustments are indexes generation based on your data and query.

The function you need for your scanrio is `max`. You have to select the `max` of `anser_id` for grouped `user_id, question_id` as following:

---

SOLUTION 1

```
@Query("select max(answer) from Answer answer where answer.deleted = false group by answer.userId, answer.questionId")
List<Answer> findLatestAnswersByUserQuestionNotDeleted();
```

This statement returns 4 record because, rightly, if you are not considering deleted answer, the latest answer of the user 1 in question 1 becomes 1.

I don't know why you didn't consider this but i will follow your question as it is.

Because of this you have to post filter programmatically deleted as described by you so the `@Query` becomes:

```
@Query("select max(answer) from Answer answer group by answer.userId, answer.questionId")
List<Answer> findLatestAnswersByUserQuestion();
```

Again you have, rightly, 4 records because also deleted is present and must be filtered programmatically

---

SOLUTION 2 (two queries, because of your requirement to ignore deleted and not consider the old one)

step 1 - findId of answers including deleted (just id):

```
@Query("select max(answer.id) from Answer answer group by answer.userId, answer.questionId")
List<Long> findLatestAnswersId();
```

step 2 - load answers by id excluding deleted

```
List<Answer> findAllByDeletedIsFalseAndIdIn(List<Long> ids);
```

---

SOLUTION 3 (one query)

```
@Query("select answer from Answer answer where answer.deleted = false and  answer.id in (select max(inAnswer.id) from Answer inAnswer)")
List<Answer> findLastestNotDeleted()
```

Comment: Thanks for addressing my question. Can it be done in one query? We would not like to transfer all data to the runtime memory to filter it there but keep calculation in the DB. It is correct that if the latest answer of a user to a specific question is deleted there should be no answer of that user to the specific question in the result. We want to do exactly what the given statement does, but we want it to be more efficient.

Comment: also with an aggregation function, you need two queries or a nested query like select max(answer.id) from (select nested Answer nested where answer.deleted = false) answer group by answer.userId, answer.questionId but nested queries are not supported in JPAQL. I think that read ids is feasible and memory efficient also (a simply list of Long). The alternative is to write native SQL query, but this way you will loose pagination, filter and also all others jpa automatism

Comment: updated with solution 3 using one query as you asked

Comment: Hey ValerioMC, I think the 3rd solution does ignore the `questionId`? We search for the max `answerId` among those with the same `questionId`

Comment: The result should be one max answer for each different question id